# jQuery menu not working correctly for menu

Tags: jquery, menu

I built this out by hand, and it worked fine in localhost, but had to integrate it into Gravity Forms, and  lost some desired functionality with the new ID's. It shows the `customer-information` div no matter what. I can never seem to get code to display right in here, so if you want, I have it at http://jsbin.com/laqoxe/edit?html,js,output

Here is the javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  //Hide all but 1st field
  $("#field_6_12").hide(); //Are you a current client?
  $("#field_6_13").hide(); //Are you a currently receiving?
  $("#field_6_14").hide(); //Are you a currently working?
  $("#field_6_15").hide(); //Are you currently unable to work?
  $("#customer-information").hide();

  // build variables
  var interested = $('input[type=radio][name=input_11]'),
    current = $("input[type=radio][name=input_12]"),
    currentlyReceiving = $("input[type=radio][name=input_13]"),
    currentlyWorking = $("input[type=radio][name=input_14]"),
    unable = $("input[type=radio][name=input_15]"),
    fname = $("input[type=radio][name=input_6]"),
    lname = $("input[type=radio][name=input_7]"),
    phone = $("input[type=radio][name=input_8]"),
    email = $("input[type=radio][name=input_9]"),
    message = $("input[type=radio][name=input_10]");
  //submitButton = $("input[type=submit]                [id=gform_submit_button_6]");


  //Conditionals
  //====================================

  //if interested changes, show current
  interested.change(function() {
    $("#field_6_12").show(); //this shows next area no matter what
  }); //  END interested change function

  //Begins when the .current changes:
  current.change(function() {
    //if veterans && current client yes:
    if (interested.val() == 'Veterans Benefits' && current.val() == 'Yes') {
      $('#customer-information').show();

      //if veteran && current client no:
    } else if (interested.val() == 'Veterans Benefits' && current.val() == 'No') {
      $('#customer-information').show();

      //if SSD && current client no:
    } else if (interested.val() == 'Social Security Disability' && current.val() == 'No') {
      $('#field_6_13').show(); //show currently Receiving

      //if Both  && current client no:
    } else if (interested.val() == 'Both' && current.val() == 'No') {
      $('#field_6_13').show(); //show currently Receiving

    }
  }); //current change function

  //begins with currentlyReceiving change
  currentlyReceiving.change(function() {
    $('#field_6_14').show(); // show currentlyWorking  (no matter what, on change.)
  });

  //begins with currentlyWorking change
  currentlyWorking.change(function() {
    $('#field_6_15').show(); // show unable (to work)  (no matter what, on change.)
  });

  //begins with unable to work change
  currentlyReceiving.change(function() {
    $('#customer-information').show(); // show #customer-information  (no matter what, on change.)
  });
}); //doc ready
```

```html
<form>
  <ul id='gform_fields_6' class='gform_fields top_label form_sublabel_below description_below'>
    <li id='field_6_11' class='gfield interested field_sublabel_below field_description_below'>
      <label class='gfield_label'>Are you interested in Social Security Disability or Veterans&#039; Disability Benefits?</label>
      <div class='ginput_container ginput_container_radio'>
        <ul class='gfield_radio' id='input_6_11'>
          <li class='gchoice_6_11_0'>
            <input name='input_11' type='radio' value='Veterans Benefits' id='choice_6_11_0' tabindex='1' />
            <label for='choice_6_11_0' id='label_6_11_0'>Veterans Benefits</label>
          </li>
          <li class='gchoice_6_11_1'>
            <input name='input_11' type='radio' value='Social Security Disability' id='choice_6_11_1' tabindex='2' />
            <label for='choice_6_11_1' id='label_6_11_1'>Social Security Disability</label>
          </li>
          <li class='gchoice_6_11_2'>
            <input name='input_11' type='radio' value='Both' id='choice_6_11_2' tabindex='3' />
            <label for='choice_6_11_2' id='label_6_11_2'>Both</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id='field_6_12' class='gfield current field_sublabel_below field_description_below'>
      <label class='gfield_label'>Are you a current client?</label>
      <div class='ginput_container ginput_container_radio'>
        <ul class='gfield_radio' id='input_6_12'>
          <li class='gchoice_6_12_0'>
            <input name='input_12' type='radio' value='Yes' id='choice_6_12_0' tabindex='4' />
            <label for='choice_6_12_0' id='label_6_12_0'>Yes</label>
          </li>
          <li class='gchoice_6_12_1'>
            <input name='input_12' type='radio' value='No' id='choice_6_12_1' tabindex='5' />
            <label for='choice_6_12_1' id='label_6_12_1'>No</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id='field_6_13' class='gfield currentlyReceiving field_sublabel_below field_description_below'>
      <label class='gfield_label'>Are you currently receiving Social Security Disablity?</label>
      <div class='ginput_container ginput_container_radio'>
        <ul class='gfield_radio' id='input_6_13'>
          <li class='gchoice_6_13_0'>
            <input name='input_13' type='radio' value='Yes' id='choice_6_13_0' tabindex='6' />
            <label for='choice_6_13_0' id='label_6_13_0'>Yes</label>
          </li>
          <li class='gchoice_6_13_1'>
            <input name='input_13' type='radio' value='No' id='choice_6_13_1' tabindex='7' />
            <label for='choice_6_13_1' id='label_6_13_1'>No</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id='field_6_14' class='gfield currentlyWorking field_sublabel_below field_description_below'>
      <label class='gfield_label'>Are you currently working more than 10 hours per week?</label>
      <div class='ginput_container ginput_container_radio'>
        <ul class='gfield_radio' id='input_6_14'>
          <li class='gchoice_6_14_0'>
            <input name='input_14' type='radio' value='Yes' id='choice_6_14_0' tabindex='8' />
            <label for='choice_6_14_0' id='label_6_14_0'>Yes</label>
          </li>
          <li class='gchoice_6_14_1'>
            <input name='input_14' type='radio' value='No' id='choice_6_14_1' tabindex='9' />
            <label for='choice_6_14_1' id='label_6_14_1'>No</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id='field_6_15' class='gfield unable field_sublabel_below field_description_below'>
      <label class='gfield_label'>Are you unable to work a full time job because of your disability?</label>
      <div class='ginput_container ginput_container_radio'>
        <ul class='gfield_radio' id='input_6_15'>
          <li class='gchoice_6_15_0'>
            <input name='input_15' type='radio' value='Yes' id='choice_6_15_0' tabindex='10' />
            <label for='choice_6_15_0' id='label_6_15_0'>Yes</label>
          </li>
          <li class='gchoice_6_15_1'>
            <input name='input_15' type='radio' value='No' id='choice_6_15_1' tabindex='11' />
            <label for='choice_6_15_1' id='label_6_15_1'>No</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <div id="customer-information">
      <li id='field_6_6' class='gfield stepSix field_sublabel_below field_description_below'>
        <label class='gfield_label' for='input_6_6'>First Name</label>
        <div class='ginput_container ginput_container_text'>
          <input name='input_6' id='input_6_6' type='text' value='' class='medium' tabindex='12' />
        </div>
      </li>



      <li id='field_6_7' class='gfield stepSix field_sublabel_below field_description_below'>
        <label class='gfield_label' for='input_6_7'>Last Name</label>
        <div class='ginput_container ginput_container_text'>
          <input name='input_7' id='input_6_7' type='text' value='' class='medium' tabindex='13' />
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id='field_6_8' class='gfield stepSix field_sublabel_below field_description_below'>
        <label class='gfield_label' for='input_6_8'>Phone</label>
        <div class='ginput_container ginput_container_phone'>
          <input name='input_8' id='input_6_8' type='text' value='' class='medium' tabindex='14' />
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id='field_6_9' class='gfield stepSix field_sublabel_below field_description_below'>
        <label class='gfield_label' for='input_6_9'>Email</label>
        <div class='ginput_container ginput_container_email'>
          <input name='input_9' id='input_6_9' type='text' value='' class='medium' tabindex='15' />
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id='field_6_10' class='gfield stepSix field_sublabel_below field_description_below'>
        <label class='gfield_label' for='input_6_10'>Message</label>
        <div class='ginput_container ginput_container_textarea'>
          <textarea name='input_10' id='input_6_10' class='textarea medium' tabindex='16' rows='10' cols='50'></textarea>
        </div>
      </li>
    </div>
    <!--/customer-information -->
  </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the radio button always stays on Veterans Benefits value. So i think you should trigger the change of the radio button inside the `current.change(function(){`
For instance if you move

```
interested =         $('input[type=radio][name=input_11]:checked'),
current =            $('input[type=radio][name=input_12]:checked'),
```

there it should work

Comment: Thank  you my friend, in the course of creating those variables, I lost the :checked property!